# parse.com bind this to success block

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a simple nested query but I can't figure out how to bind the "this" variable to the success block. I'm including a few extra lines of code to give a little more context.

```
  initialize: function() {

        _.bindAll(this, 'addAll', 'addOne', 'logOut', 'newJob', 'showDetail');

        this.$el.html(_.template($("#manage-jobs-template").html()));

        this.jobs = new JobList;
        this.requests = new RequestList;

        this.jobs.query = new Parse.Query(Job);
        this.jobs.query.equalTo('jobPostedBy', Parse.User.current());
        this.jobs.fetch({

          success: function (jobs) {
            //This is undefined here. 
            this.requests.query = new Parse.Query(Request);
            this.requests.query.containsAll("job", jobs);
            this.requests.fetch();
          }

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to save a reference to `this` inside the `initialize` function, then use it in your `success` function. `self` will be available inside `success`:

```
initialize: function(){
    var self = this;
    ...
    this.jobs.fetch({
        success: function(jobs){
            self.request.query = ... //--- here self references the "outer" this
            ....
        }
    });
}
```

Another solution is to bind the context to the anonymous function with `bind()`:

```
initialize: function(){
    ...
    this.jobs.fetch({
        success: (function(jobs){
            this.request.query = ... 
            ....
        }).bind(this); //--- context binding
    });
}
```

have a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/8e8yfxx9/3/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! +1 for two solutions. Now off investigating why containsAll is not working :)....